# Read multiple files one by one and process in python

Tags: python

I am using Pybrain (neural Network library) in python for image processing. I have 196 files in a directory and it is saved in all_files in the code below. I tried to open each file and do processing on each file separately but it is taking all files data in one string, I want each file to open one by one, do processing and output
here is my code:

```
from pybrain.datasets import SupervisedDataSet
from pybrain.supervised.trainers import BackpropTrainer
import glob
ds = SupervisedDataSet(121,121)

all_files = glob.glob('/home/vidula/Desktop/tp/inpt/./*.data')
for filename in all_files:
   indata = tuple()
   outdata = tuple()
   with open(filename,'r')as file:
      for line in file.readlines():
          d = line.strip().split( ',' )
          indata = indata +  (d[0], )
          outdata = outdata + ( d[1], )
          ds.addSample(indata, outdata)
print outdata
```

Can anybody help me out?

Comment: Edit question and fix indent to match actual code -- eg `for line...` after `with open(...` is at wrong indent.  Also shouldn't indata and outdata be initialized and used within the `for filename in...` loop, instead of before and after it completes?

Comment: You're using `file` as a variable name, and it's also the name of a Python built-in function. It's best to avoid using the names of Python built-ins for your variables, as it will cause problems if you later want to use the built-in as well.

Comment: I don't know pybrain but are you sure you want to add the whole cumulative indata and outdata to the sample each time? Don't you just want to add the data from the newest line, i.e. `ds.addSample((d[0], ), (d[1], ))`. Or alternatively put the `ds.addSample` outside of the `for line...` loop so that it adds the sample only after having read each file?

Comment: @Stuart- I dot want to add whole data to the sample but  I want to add according to file, each file data should be added to the sample one by one

Answer (score 2):

You need to reset indata and outdata before you read each file. ie

```
for filename in all_files:
    indata = tuple()
    outdata = tuple()
```

Comment: @vids: I know you are welcome. Please select and vote up this answer.